# CMake project in Visual Studio gives flag override warnings (Command line warning D9025: overriding '/W4' with '/w')

Tags: visual-c++, cmake, compiler-warnings, visual-studio-2019

I have a CMake project, which I am building with Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I am trying to fix and remove all warnings, but there is one type which I can't disable or fix.

All of them are of the type:

```
Command line warning D9025: overriding '/W4' with '/w'
Command line warning D9025: overriding '/W3' with '/W4'
```

I tried fixing them, but I can't find out what's causing all of them.

My question is:

How can I disable the warnings using CMake? Or is there a surefire way to find the underlying cause of them and fix them?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This issue has been raised ([here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/18317) and [here](https://cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-January/034669.html)), and depending on your CMake version there are a couple solutions.

When building for MSVC with CMake, the compiler warning flags (like `/W3`) are added by default. In CMake 3.15, CMake introduced a [fix](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/merge_requests/3250) for this, and the compiler warning flags are no longer automatically added so the warning should no longer appear. From the docs:

> CMake 3.15 and above prefer to leave out warning flags from the value of `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS` by default.

Along with this fix, CMake introduced policy [CMP0092](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0092.html), which allows you to switch back to the `OLD` behavior (adding the warning flags by default) if necessary.

---

If you are tied to a CMake version older than 3.15, you can manually manipulate the [`CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_FLAGS) variable to replace the warnings yourself using CMake's [regular expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/string.html#regular-expressions). You can try something like this:

```
string(REGEX REPLACE "/W[3|4]" "/w" CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
```

Comment: I am getting this issue even with CMake 3.19.2 on Visual Studio 2019 Pro edition.

Comment: This is probably because your minimum required CMake version is less than 3.15, you need to use at least 3.15 in your project:

`cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)`

Comment: Do I need to explicitly define this flag in CMAKElist.txt "CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS"

Comment: I tried to suppress warnings from external libraries with /external:W0 flag, and I am getting similar issue: "overriding /external:W3 with /external:W0".
My cmake_minimum_required is 3.18.

Comment: Maybe it's obvious for some but I was having the issue persist after I've increased required version until I've done `Delete Cache and Reconfigure` from within msvc. Seems like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` value still stays in the cache otherwise.

Comment: Is there a generic solution for other flags (like /Zi) or if you want to change the warning level in a subproject? Or you still need to resort to ugly string regex replace?

Answer (score 7):

I had this problem even though I was using CMake 3.19. It was caused by having the `project` command before the `cmake_minimum_required` command.